# are there any compiled lists of modern equivalents of historical proverbs?

Tags: idioms

I'm not even sure of what we commonly label these types of expressions that are passed down from generations.

Some are attributed to the bible, like, "idle hands are the devil's workshop." 
 There are others like, "don't look a gift horse in the mouth."

I like to quiz family members on these expressions at get-togethers, but the younger generation tells me they are relics from the dinosaur age and an unfair test of cultural aptitude.

Are they mostly obsolete in this generation's culture (media, literature, etc)?  And is there some set of commonly used expressions that are current and have been compiled somewhere?

Edit: to clarify, I am looking for a source of modern equivalents of historical proverbs.  Now that I'm more aware of the best terminology, the question (hopefully) is more appropriate.

Comment: Why don’t you ask your younger family members?  I don’t think the expressions you mention have lost their relevancy.

Comment: They are called idioms. Some are centuries old and haven't lost their relevancy. Because many harken back to agrarian times (some from the Greeks), it is true that the young must be taught some of the idioms, but most eventually pick it them up by exposure to their culture. My kids know their idioms. There is a lot on the internet about idioms - just search "English idioms" (British/etc.)

Comment: very interesing, although after looking up a few sites, I wonder if they might be more properly classified as proverbs. Or whether both might just be a subest of some higher class of expressions.  Anyways, I always thought children picked up a lot of these through cultural mediums, and whether they are more timely than timeless (as evidenced from some of my younger family members).

Comment: They are indeed proverbial. And to "piggyback" on medica's comment, the collective unconscious of the younger generation is inventing their own idioms, or “fixed phrases,” as every generation does. Idioms are a kind of cultural shorthand, linguistic distillates of common and enduring human experience. Most of the “new” idioms will be recapitulations of their predecessors, containing the same old kernels of wisdom in a contemporary setting, they will be, as it were, but “new wine in old bottles.”

Comment: @dwjohnston this OP won't remain open without a specific English language question, like: what are expressions like "That's the way the cookie crumbles" or "idle hands ..." called? Can you assist with another edit?

Comment: Or maybe it's, "old wine in new bottles"!

Comment: @LittleEva I think editing to make the question ask “what are these  thinge called” is so far from the original intent of the question that I think that wouldn’t be a good edit.

Comment: You're probably right, but at least in the title the OP **seemed** to be trying to ask, "what are these called?" In any case, it's GR, and has effectively been answered already, @Jim

Comment: @LittleEva  I think it was asking for a list not a name. I.e. What do kids nowadays say instead of ‘that’s how the cookie crumbles’ and likewise for all the other “old” expressions.

Comment: [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+way+the+cookie+crumbles%2Cshit+happens%2Cc%27est+la+vie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20way%20the%20cookie%20crumbles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshit%20happens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20la%20vie%3B%2Cc0) is useful to compare similar expressions. Like "the way the cookie crumbles," "shit happens," and "c'est la vie."

Comment: @stevesliva. That's a very cool trending comparison tool. Only, i would first need a list of modern expressions to compare.

Comment: @pat, yep.  Just a comment.  It's interesting to me that there are so many synonyms for that particular idiom.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, so only a comment . "The way the cookie crumbles"  is not a proverb. It is a kind of saying that I would expect from younger people who like to use clever-sounding sayings which actually say nothing. All the times I have been trying to find a label for this kind of empty talk. But I found nothing but "empty sayings".

Comment: If you look at an English language website for learners, the idioms, proverbs etc. they list will tend to be the most common for obvious reasons. E.g. http://www.ieltsbuddy.com/common-idioms.html; http://www.smart-words.org/quotes-sayings/idioms-meaning.html ; http://testprep.about.com/od/englishlanguagetests/a/English_Idioms.htm and phrases which are often incorrectly used/said http://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/25-common-phrases-that-youre-saying-wrong.html

Comment: http://www.learn-english-today.com/proverbs/proverbs.html

Comment: @rogermue - *that's the way the cookie crumbles* may not be a proverb, but it is *proverbial* and, used appropriately, it's certainly not nonsense, rather it expresses the same stoic fatalism encapsulated in the French, *c'est la vie* and Italian, *lo que será, sera*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways to characterize succinct expressions of commonsense wisdom—including such terms as *proverbs*, *sayings*, *adages*, *aphorisms*, *apothegms*, *saws*, and *homilies*—and they are constantly being supplemented by new expressions that have caught on and achieved some degree of cultural resonance.

Evidence of the ever-emerging nature of such sayings appears in *The [Yale] Dictionary of Modern Proverbs* (2012), which consists of discussions of "more than 1400" (but presumably less than 1500) proverbs that have emerged since 1900—fragments of relatively new folk wisdom like "The sky is the limit" (1909) and "It's a jungle out there" (1951) and "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" (1960) and "The game isn't over till the fat lady sings" (1984) and "Even a dead cat will bounce" (1987) and "He who dies with the most toys still dies" (1993) and "If you aren't lying, you aren't trying" (2004).

Conversely, popular sayings of the past often fall into disuse and become unknown to succeeding generations. Thus the following proverbs—among many others—reported by Nathan Bailey in his *Dictionarium Britannicum* (1736) are new to me: "Soldiers in peace are like chimnies in summer." "Every man's nose will not make a shoeing-horn." "The clerk forgets that ever he was a sexton." "Drunken folks seldom take harm." "A bushel of March dust is worth a king's ransom." "Light suppers make clean sheets." "An inch breaks no squares."

The point is not that we are poorer than our forebears in such wisdom (although I don't doubt that I would be wiser if I understood why it makes sense to say "An inch breaks no squares"), and that our progeny will be poorer than us, but that proverbs are a kind of river of commonsense wisdom that replenishes itself as it rushes along.

Comment: "An inch breaks no squares." You haven't got the sense of it?

Comment: @LittleEva: Nathan Bailey interprets it thus: "That is, it is hardly worth while to break off a bargain or contest an argument or dispute with a neighbour or friend for a trifle." So I understand the intention of it, but not what sort of square the proverb is talking about, nor why an inch might have been feared (unreasonably) to break it.

Comment: Well, that's a start. I hadn't a clue. An inch is the trifle, the square represents the larger value, but how?

Comment: Solid & reliable?

Comment: Here is John Heywood, _Proverbes_ (1562) on "Breaking the Square": "_An inch breaketh no square_ : which, since thou hast heard tell,/Thou dost assys how to break square by an ell." And again (same source): "_An inch breaketh no square_ : thou breakest none, though it do;/Thou rather bringest square than breakest square between two." Both of these couplets consist of the original saying plus Heywood's poetical play on it; in the first instance he seems to connect it to the conflicting proverb "Give someone an inch and they will take an ell." Anyway, it's an old, old saying.

Comment: And here is John Ray, _A Collection of English Proverbs_ (1678) adding a further complication: "An inch breaks no squares. _Some add_, in a burn of thorns." Here, a _burn_ is presumably a creek or stream, but a _square_ is ... I still don't know what.

Comment: Give someone a hand and they'll take an arm.

Comment: Never give a square an even break.

Comment: @SvenYargs We're square. Nothing more to settle.  It's a square deal now.  Everything is proper.

Comment: @stevesliva: You know, I finally figured out while blundering around in the books of proverbs mentioned above that the saying probably originated in architecture: "An inch [out of true] doesn't break a square." In other words, even if a building when constructed is only approximately square, its being an inch off doesn't matter: A 1-inch error doesn't mean that the square isn't still square. It was the singular _inch_ and the plural _squares_ in Bailey's version that had me chasing my own tail.